# UTF8 not displaying in rxvt-unicode

Tags: linux, locale, unicode, rxvt

My XTERM works perfectly with UTF-8, but I want a lighter terminal. I am trying to use UTF-8 in rxvt, so I am using rxvt-unicode (urxvt) in Fedora 32 fully updated. But UTF-8 files are not render properly (e.g., with cat), as if it were a Latin1 console. I removed my .Xdefault and .Xresources files, no difference. My locale is set properly. The command I use to start the `urxvt` is this:

```
urxvt -fn "9x15bold,xft:Bitstream Vera Sans Mono" -imlocale en_US.UTF-8
```

Adding `-letsp 0` doesn't work. Some data:

```
$ perl -le 'print "\x{c3}\x{94}"'
Ã

$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

$ echo $TERM
rxvt-unicode-256color

$ rpm -q rxvt-unicode
rxvt-unicode-9.22-23.fc32.x86_6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a single font, e.g. here's my

```
~/.Xdefaults
URxvt.font: xft:Terminus:pixelsize=20:antialias=false
URxvt.depth: 32
URxvt.background: #000000
URxvt.foreground: #EEEEEE
URxvt.cursorColor: #FFFFFF
URxvt.scrollBar_right: True
URxvt.scrollBar_floating: True
URxvt.saveLines: 32767
URxvt.cursorBlink: False
```

[image]

Comment: Nope, same problem, just a lot bigger. :)  `urxvt` seems to work exactly as `rxvt`.

Comment: I'm currently running Fedora 32 with the provided config and font and as you can see everything works. Maybe you should try this exact configuration.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear: I tried your config.

Comment: Did you run urxvt normally? I.e. without any additional command like flags? As you can see it works here.

Comment: Yes, same problem, even as root and with your ~/.Xdefaults, and after reinstalling `rxvt-unicode`. My `rxvt-unicode` is from the updates repo. Very strange... Is there a way to load urxvt without any config? Maybe it is loading something in the system that is not right.

Comment: Launch another terminal emulator, run `strace -e file urxvt` - you will then see what exactly it opens.

Comment: That was a great advice. I saw `urxvt` reading iso-8859-1 locales (my default environment). It seems it is not enough to set the `urxvt` locales (say, en_US.UTF-8) after launch: it is needed before launch also (why?). Now it works. Actually, normal `rxvt` also renders UTF-8 correctly now. Thanks!

Comment: In particular, I had to set all `LC_XXX` variables in a file inside `$HOME/.config/plasma-workspace/env`, since KDE got wrong encoding too.